# Stochastic dominance in a Banach lattice

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

For real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$, if $X$ is strictly first-order stochastically dominated by $Y$, then $\mathbf{E}X < \mathbf{E}Y$ (where $\mathbf{E}$ is the expectation operator, and assuming both expectations are well-defined). Is the same true for random variables that take values in an arbitrary Banach lattice?

To be explicit, by strict first-order stochastic dominance I mean that for all $x$ in the Banach lattice, $P(X \ge x) \le P(Y \ge x)$, and for some $x$, $P(X \ge x) < P(Y \ge x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the answer is no: this is just the wrong definition of stochastic dominance for more general orders than $\mathbb{R}$.

Here's a simple counterexample. Consider the Banach lattice $\mathbb{R}^2$, ordered by $(x_1, x_2) \le (y_1, y_2)$ iff $x_1 \le y_1$ and $x_2 \le y_2$. Then consider random variables with the following distributions:
$$\begin{aligned}
X &&& (-2,-2): 1/3 \quad (1,0): 1/3 \quad (0,1): 1/3 \\
Y &&& (-2,-2): 1/2 \quad (1,1): 1/2
\end{aligned}$$
Then $Y$ "stochastically dominates" $X$ in the sense given in the question, but the expected value of $X$ is $(-1/3, -1/3)$, while the expected value of $Y$ is $(-1/2, -1/2)$.

I think the issue is that the upper sets of the form $\{ y : y \ge x \}$ don't carry enough information to pin down more general upper sets, like the set $A = \{ x ∈ \mathbb{R}^2 ∣ x \ge (1,0) \text{ or } x \ge (0,1) \}$ in the example. The probability that $X$ takes a value in $A$ is higher than the probability that $Y$ takes a value in $A$.